# Disable the discount box on Shopify Mobile Web Checkout

Tags: html, css, shopify

I've created a Shopify store where discount codes can be entered indirectly. Therefore I am trying to disable the discount box as seen below.

[image]

I've researched it and seen you can edit the code in Themes > Actions > Edit Code.
And I've followed some videos:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJi6zfc63RU

However I am unable to do it.

Has anyone done this before?

Please Help!

Comment: What do you mean when you say that discount codes can be entered indirectly? Do you use Shopify discounts or some custom implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right place, you need to look for the "checkout.liquid" file to make that edit.

Looks like you need to have a Shopify Plus account to be able to access that specific file, and lacks a workaround because of the security necessary to keep that page PCI compliant.

You can see more here: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Discussion/Customizing-Checkout-Page/td-p/453743